Models Origin Points Won't Move
I merged the mesh but there are still these lines and points here which won't join to the model or move with it, at first I just ignored them but they seem to be messing with the physics and if I delete them the model goes haywire. There are eight points in total. How do I fix this or make it so it moves with the car model?
The lines are faint and hard to see, but you can see them around the origin of the 3d space and connecting it to the car. Also when I highlight everything and attempt to parent I get the error "Loop in Parents".
Sorry if this is an obvious question!

They are relationship lines which show that parts or all of your model is already parented which is also the reason for your loop error. I would guess that Empties are involved but aren't visible in your image. Add an image of your complete Blender window showing the Outliner using Blender's built-in Window Save Screenshot menu and possibly share your file here via https://blend-exchange.com/ and we'll be able to give you a more definitive answer.
